# Set protocols in an NSObject class and call them in a UIViewController class

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

i'm new to swift and I just wonder is there a way to declare some delegate protocols in an NSObject class and call them in an UIViewController class. I tried doing it and it trows an runtime exception. My code in the classes as bellow.

NSObject class

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit
class InAppPurchase: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
var productsList = [SKProduct]()
    var productToPurchase = SKProduct()
    var productID = ""
    let PURCHASE_ID_PREFIX = "com.aux.ApplePaySample."


    public func initPayment (productID: String) {
        self.productID = PURCHASE_ID_PREFIX + productID
        print("Initializing Purchase Product ID: \(self.productID)")
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: self.productID)
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }else {
            print("In App Purchases not enabled")
        }
    }

    func buyProduct() {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment as SKPayment)
    }


    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        let myProducts = response.products
        for product in myProducts {
            print("\(product.productIdentifier) \(product.price) \(product.localizedDescription)")
            productsList.append(product)
        }

        for product in productsList {
            let productID = product.productIdentifier
            if productID == self.productID {
                productToPurchase = product
                buyProduct()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

UIViewController class

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class InAppViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet var buyButton: UIButton!
    // SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver 
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var product_id: NSString?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    InAppPurchase().initPayment(productID: "101")
}
```

Technically my initPayment method should trigger the delegates, but its not happening and I'm not getting what I'm missing here. Help would much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

should create an instance as bellow

```
static var shared:InAppPurchase = {
        return InAppPurchase()
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't retaining your InAppPurchase object.  Chances are it's getting released and set to nil before the delegate is getting called.

Try creating a class variable `var iap: InAppPurchase` and then assigning to that variable when instantiating your class.

```
iap = InAppPurchase()
iap.initPayment(productID: "101")
```

This should retain your instance and allow it to receive the delegate method calls.